# Array in post converts to string

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

in html if you do

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <select multiple name="items[]">
    <option value....
```

the post result will be an array.  With vue, if you do

```
<input type="hidden" name="items[]" v-model="myArray">
```

you get back an array with one element containing a string "1,2,3".  Essentially, v-model converts into a string on the post request.  How can I get it to post an actual array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the result of anything `v-model` is doing. Even in vanilla JavaScript/HTML, if you set an array value to an input and post it, you will get a string.

In order to post an array (without ajax) from `<input>`, you need multiple `<input>` with the same name:

```js
<input
  type="hidden"
  name="items[]"
  v-for="(item, index) in myArray"
  :key="index"
  :value="item"
/>
```

No need for `v-model` either since the input is hidden.